# Enable EFS for whole system partition

Tags: efs

When I try to apply EFS for the Windows system partition, there's many files error with "access denied". How to override the restriction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot encrypt Windows system files with EFS. The encryption key is tied to your user account and only unlocked after boot & login – but how would you unlock it for booting the OS, if the OS [needs to be decrypted first?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catch-22_(logic))

If you need full disk encryption, use BitLocker instead. (The TPM requirement can be disabled.) Alternatively see if VeraCrypt supports OS drive encryption for your version.

Comment: Bitlocker is a pain on Windows 7 without TPM: https://superuser.com/questions/1225011/windows-7-bitlocker-with-no-tpm-nor-usb-key-use-startup-pin-only

Comment: @Sam - You cannot accomplish FDE with EFS, end of story, Bitlocker is the FDE solution for Windows